# Get Intersecting roads using ArcGIS Server with Silverlight API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I am developing a tool where when I click on a road in the map I have to list the roads intersecting the selected road
using ArcGIS Server10 with silverlight API

to develop this tool
I got the roadID of the selected road using IdentifyQuery
Then I got the envelope of that road using QueryTask
I passed that road envelope to IdentifyTask again and queried the intersecting roads

but its lists me all the roads inside the envelope but I need only intersecting roads
also its very very slow :(
I am stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried it, but according to the [REST API documentation for Identify](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/identify.html), instead of passing an envelope, you should be able to pass the geometry of the road with a tolerance of 0.

Another option (which I have tried) is to call the [Query method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/query.html) and pass the road's geometry with `esriSpatialRelIntersects`.

The nice thing about Identify is that it substitutes coded value domains to make the results more presentable.  Query just returns codes.

Comment: yep QueryTask worked fine,esriSpatialRelIntersects did the trick : Thnks a bunch

Comment: @Santoh: please DO mark Kirk's post as correct to give him some credit for taking the time to answer your question.